# How do I make the first section of UITableView appear at a certain distance from the top border programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    print("Inside viewForHeader")
    if(section > 0){

    let headerView = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
    headerView.titleLabel?.text = myOrders.allmyorders[section].customerOrder.number
    let dunamicButton = UIButton(type : UIButtonType.System)
    dunamicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    dunamicButton.setTitle("Order number: \(myOrders.allmyorders[section].customerOrder.number)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    dunamicButton.tag = section
    dunamicButton.frame = headerView.frame
    dunamicButton.enabled = true
    dunamicButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    headerView.addSubview(dunamicButton)
    return headerView
    }


    else {
        let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
        let dunamicButton = UIButton(type : UIButtonType.System)
        dunamicButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        dunamicButton.setTitle("Order number: \(myOrders.allmyorders[section].customerOrder.number)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        dunamicButton.tag = section
        dunamicButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 377, 30)
        dunamicButton.enabled = true
        dunamicButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        headerView.addSubview(dunamicButton)

        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        let buttonActive = UIButton(type : UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
        buttonActive.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        buttonActive.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        buttonActive.layer.borderWidth = 1
        buttonActive.alpha = 0.3
        buttonActive.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        buttonActive.setTitle("Active Orders", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonActive.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonActive.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width/2,40)
        buttonActive.addTarget(self, action: "ActiveOrdersPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        let buttonAllMyOrders = UIButton(type : UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
        buttonAllMyOrders.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        buttonAllMyOrders.setTitle("All My Orders", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonAllMyOrders.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        buttonAllMyOrders.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        buttonAllMyOrders.layer.borderWidth = 1
        buttonAllMyOrders.alpha = 0.3
        buttonAllMyOrders.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        buttonAllMyOrders.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2,0,self.view.frame.size.width/2,40)
        buttonAllMyOrders.addTarget(self, action: "AllMyOrdersOrdersPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        headerView.addSubview(buttonActive)
        headerView.addSubview(buttonAllMyOrders)

        return headerView

    }
```

`

I'm new to swift and I wish to make the first section of my UITableView appear at a certain distance from the top border. I need to do this to accomodate two buttons. 
The problem I am facing now is that my buttons overlaps my first section.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ssjg.png)

Comment: How are you creating and laying out your objects? Programmatically or using a storyboard scene?  Either way the answer is via NSLayoutConstraints but you will,either add them programmatically or via InterfaceBuilder. Also are you using a view controller or a tableviewcontroller?

Comment: Hello, sith lord from star wars! provide your code first so that we can see what you have tried so far-----From a humble Jedi ;)

Comment: Laying out programmatically. I just made the UITableView in storyboard. The rest I added programmatically.

Comment: @DarthVader: Provide code you must !!!!

Comment: I added buttons on my sections. They display the corresponding cells for that section on pressing.

Comment: you need to  make the header view's background color opaque rather than clear as a table section will scroll "under" the header view

Comment: Can you explain it in code? @Paulw11

Comment: Where you say `headerView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()` say `headerView.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()` or whatever background color you want your header view to have. The header view is inside the table view so you can't move the tableview down; the header view will just move down too. You need to make the header view background a solid color so that it hides the cells as they scroll under it

Comment: The problem still persists @Paulw11

Comment: Can you still see the content as it moves under the header?  You are never going to have the buttons outside the table if you use a header view

Comment: Strange, it looks from your image that the rows are scrolling on top of the header view rather than under

Comment: I still see the section content being overlapped by the two buttons.

Comment: Have you tried implementing `heightForHeaderInSection:`?

Comment: No. The buttons are overlapping the section.  If I press All My Orders or Active Orders , corresponding events are triggered.

Comment: I tried that. Though I want to know how you wish to use the  heightForHeaderInSection: .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection` and return the height of the header view for section 0 which as per your code is 40.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. What I did was the return

```
tableView: heightForHeaderInSection
```

at section 0 as 100 and for the remaining I kept it as default 40. and I made the dunamicButton frame for section 0 as

```
dunamicButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 377, 30)
```

[The sneaky section 0 that was hiding finally showed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qasac.png)

May the Force be with you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this method

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

. After setting a height you set you use this method

- (nullable UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;

  with constrains. How much distance you want from top border.